# remove periods from fasta file using python

Tags: python, fasta

I'm new to python (using 2.7) and I'm trying to take a fasta file of aligned sequences and remove the periods (.) and dashes (-). I'm trying to write a loop so that python goes through each line and replaces the periods and dashes with nothing. This is the script I've got (when I run it, it removes the periods and dashes but leaves spaces behind):

```
InFileName = 'myfile.fasta'
InFile = open(InFileName, 'r')

OutFileName = 'myfile_nodots.fasta'
OutFile = open(OutFileName, 'w')

for Line in InFile:

     Line=Line.replace('.', "")

     Line=Line.replace('-', "")

     Outfile.write(Line) 

InFile.close()
OutFile.close()
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Jen

Comment: What is your question?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Variable names in Python should be lowercase. Uppercase is reserved for classes by convention.

Comment: What I have now removes the periods and dashes but doesn't eliminate the space left behind(I thought putting replace('.', '') would get rid of the space left behind)

Comment: Just as a note from the Python world: you normally don't capitalize variable names, capitalizing the first letter is usually reserved for Classes.

Comment: Why should it? You're asking it to remove the dot, not any space. Which spaces do you want to remove? Those following a dot or a dash? All spaces?

Comment: I thought writing replace('.','') would take the periods and replace them with '' (no spaces).

Comment: Yes, it should. Your code runs fine for me, as long as I change Outfile.write(Line) to OutFile.write(Line) (with a capital F). What kind of encoding are you using?

Comment: oops, that small f was a typo on here (not in my code), it still looks weird on mine! I think I'm using UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can streamline the code a bit:

```
import re
infilename = 'myfile.fasta'
outfilename = 'myfile_nodots.fasta'
regex = re.compile("[.-]+")    

with open(infilename, 'r') as infile, open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(regex.sub("", line))
```

If you also want to remove spaces that follow a dot or a dash, use a different regex:

```
regex = re.compile("[.-]+ *")
```

Comment: :') I was wondering how to use regular expressions with this but just couldn't get it straight in my head! thank you!

Comment: This works :) Regex might be a little heavyweight for such a simple op though. Try `line.translate(None, '.-')`.

Comment: This code has one minus, if the header contains dashes and dots it will remove them there as well, so it should skip all lines that starts with '>'

Answer (score 3):

You can tidy up your code to use `with` to ensure files are closed, and in 2.7 use the second parameter of `str.translate` to specify characters to remove, so your code could be:

```
with open('myfile.fasta') as fin, open('myfile_nodots.fasta', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(line.translate(None, '-.'))
```

Comment: Probably one of the neatest and most pythonic solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fileinput` and `translate` for quick in-place editing:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("test.txt", inplace=1):
    sys.stdout.write(line.translate(None, '-.'))
```

And before you ask: yes, it writes to the file, not to the console :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that fasta headers may contain dashes or dots as well(i.e. isoforms), which is quite common,

```
with open('myfile.fasta') as fin:
    with open('myfile_nodots.fasta', 'w') as fout:
        for line in fin:
            if line.startswith('>'):
                fout.write(line)
            else:
                fout.write(line.translate(None, '-.'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `Outfile.write(Line.strip())`?

Comment: No, would that just replace the Outfile.write(Line) part?

Comment: This would strip trailing and leading whitespace from each line before writing which is not what's required.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood the question :) -1 is highly accurate here.